# Is static pointer a strong pointer?

Tags: objective-c

In objective-c, I know that a static variable (should?) retain its value for the lifetime of the program. But if it stores a pointer, does it count as **strong** in ARC? Can I depend on it and be assured that that instance will **never** go out of the heap once I assigned it to a static variable?

```
static ClassA* shared;

-(id)init
{
   if (self=[super init]) {
       shared=self;
   }
   return self;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can rely on it, once it's assigned.

The [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) state:

> Under ARC, strong is the default for object types.

and then:

> __strong is the default. An object remains “alive” as long as there is a strong pointer to it.

Given your `static` pointer references the object, it will remain “alive”.  The scope of a pointer (whether global, a pointer on the stack or an instance variable) makes no difference.

Comment: I'm actually using this static pointer as a global pointer for part of my project (I know global variable is evil, but...); if it stays in the heap, how can I get rid of it once I don't want it anymore? Ideally ARC should take care of this as if there's no code using this variable then it will get dealloced; but then it seems that this static variable will mess everything up

Comment: @yulan6248 `nil` the variable when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should just be implementing a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and then you can get rid of it by setting the instance to nil.

Comment: But if the static pointer is a strong one, doesn't it mean I can only nil it in the singleton class itself? So I have to make a method dedicated for this..

Comment: If you are using ARC you don't really care about collection. If you nil it the memory that it was using will get reclaimed, right?

Comment: I think I'm confused. If the static variable is a strong pointer, then I need to set it to nil for ARC to dealloc it properly; but since the static variable is only visible to the singleton class I have to nil it inside the singleton class...Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah you would have to nil it from inside, like have a method: 'deactivate' or something, and then if someone asked for a reference again, it would recreate it.